# NodeJs Backend & Flutter Mobile App with Google Auth

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working on a backend app in  NodeJS for a mobile application. We want to authenticate with GoogleOAuth in addition to the regular email and password.
However, I am quite confused as to how the communication between the mobile app and the backend will work in relation to handling the Google OAuth specifically.
Can anyone help me with any resource or standard flow of communication between the mobile app and backend?
I am using MongoDB by the way and have already set up email and password authentication with JWT as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I recommend you first learn how to communicate with server
there are several tutorials out there in YouTube
you could search for `flutter api` or `how to use http package in flutter` so on so forth.
for google authentication there is official package from google
you could find tutorials again in YouTube . after using that package would return token which you need to pass that to token to server using DIO or HTTP package
All thing you need is learn that how to  communicate with server